# Запрос MySQL с преобразованием Unix timestamp в дату

Tags: mysql

Добрый день.

У меня есть такой запрос:

```
Query.CommandText = "SELECT joined FROM `members` WHERE xxxxx = 5";
Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**joined** в БД хранится в Unix timestamp.

Как мне при получении значения **joined** сразу же преобразовать её в нормальную дату?

Comment: Судя по этому http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html функция `FROM_UNIXTIME`

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, получилось. Но, можешь подсказать, как убрать время? Пробовал через FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x'), вообще белиберду какую-то выводит.

Comment: Разобрался! Большое спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Для решения задачи удобно воспользоваться MySQL-функцией `FROM_UNIXTIME()`

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
+------------------------------------------------------+
| FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') |
+------------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-07-06 09:21:38                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------+
```